# How to sanitize Django Rest Framework inputs

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, xss

How to sanitize the charfield in Django Rest Framework Using Serializer Or Django models itself. No idea how to secure

This value can be makes my app vulnerable.... Like **XSS**

```
<script>alert('Hacked')</script>
```

Check the serializer code

```
    class Meta:
        model = MyDB
        fields = ['id','name','price','isAvailable','isVeg','hotelID']

        read_only_fields = ['id']
```

I Have seen **Bleach**. But it feels like not dynamic, i.e cant be applied to all input field at same time.

Is any option that can be used dynamic. I'm not pro in Django so please suggest me

Comment: Can you show a case where you save `<script>alert('Hacked')</script>` in your database and you manage to display it in a page without having been re-encoded by Django ? Because Django make the checking by default normally

Comment: I use React for frontend. Anyhow React is Immune to XSS. But my problem is I scared of any unnecessary characters in my database or beeing displayed.

Comment: There is two ways for making the security checking for XSS: - Clean input data with the problems of losing real data sent, dificulty to check all input ways...etc - and the second ways, clear when your displaying data. Django uses the second solution and i think it is not a good idea to try to change this behaviour without good reason.